# Which sentence is correct? Tenses

Tags: have

I want to confirm with my customer that they received an overshipment few days ago

Which one is correct? Or can i use all of them? For me 3 below sentences are seem to be okay.. but probably I’m wrong:)

1. As I understand correctly you have received product which has not been ordered by you.
2. As I understand correctly you received product which was not ordered by you.
3. As I understand correctly you received product which you didn't order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about one past action (1) which happened before another past action (2), you should use Past Perfect Tense for action (1), and Past Simple Tense for action (2).
In the given example the earlier action is ordering, and the following is receiving.
Thus the sentence should be:
   As I understand correctly, you received the product which you had not ordered.
or
   As I understand correctly, you received the product which had not been ordered by you.
I would use the first, just to avoid passive voice.
In my opinion the explanation appears in every grammar book in section describiing tenses of the verb.